# Ember.js : How to modify data in RESTSerializer

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to modify the attributes in model.
models/example.js:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  value: DS.attr('number'),

  modified_value: function() {
    /*Some Calculations*/
    return modified_value
  }.property('value'),
})
```

above code works fine, but it creates another extra attribute in model. So to avoid this,I want to move it to the RESTSerializer. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file (example.js) in directory transforms.

```
export default DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return serialized;
    // if (serialized) {
    //   return JSON.stringify(serialized);
    // } else {
    //   return '';
    // }
  },

  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return deserialized;
    // if (deserialized) {
    //   return JSON.stringify(deserialized);
    // } else {
    //   return [];
    // }
  }
});
```

In your model file example change the attr to DS.attr('example')

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  value: DS.attr('example'),
```